# Отправка ajax через письмо

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, email

Задача такова. Переслать информацию отправленную на почту в другую базу сайта. Возможно ли это? К пример всунуть ajax скрипт в структуру шаблона письма? Или отправить в тот момент, когда оно отправляется с сервера? Есть идеи как реализовать данную задумку?

Comment: Любой уважающий себя почтовый клиент не даст провернуть такую ересь из соображений безопасности. И вообще это похоже на [XY-проблему](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709/181100). Что вы пытаетесь этим решить?

Comment: `Задача такова. Переслать информацию отправленную на почту в другую базу сайта. ` ....... нет, это извращенная задача, которую вы придумали на основе той, что вам реально нужно сделать. Вот если бы вы изначальную задачу описали - было бы гораздо лучше

Comment: отправить в тот момент, когда оно отправляется с сервера

Comment: Серверным скриптом, проверять почтовый ящик, получать новые письма, получить информацию из них и сохранить в базу.

Comment: Непонятно зачем вы добавляете почту в эту задачу. Что-то не так с формулировкой условий.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почтовые клиенты не разрешают внедрять скрипты в письма. Думаю лучший вариант это добавлять в базу до функции отправки письма.

Comment: или скорее после.... если отправка была успешна... А то вдруг письмо не удалось отправить а тут и запрос в БД ненужный прилетит

Comment: Спасибо, думаю это единственный вариант.